# react-native, bundling failed

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, npm

I am new to react-native and have found an error that makes absolutely no sense to me.

I am trying to include a calendar library: https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

I have included the dependency for that library in my *package.json* file and run `npm install`

The project was running fine and as expected. I have simply added one line of code to the project:

```
import { Calendar, CalendarList, Agenda } from 'react-native-calendars';
```

Nothing else. However now I am getting a red error message when the app loads on device and this is what my console is saying:

> error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `xdate`
>   from file
>   `/Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/react-native-calendars/src/index.js`,
>   the package
>   `/Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/xdate/package.json`
>   was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a
>   `main` module field that could not be resolved
>   (`/Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/xdate/src/xdate.js`.
>   Indeed, none of these files exist:
>
> *
>   `/Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/xdate/src/xdate.js(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
>
> *
>   `/Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/xdate/src/xdate.js/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
>       at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:103:15)
>       at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:272:4579)
>       at dependencies.map.relativePath (/Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:376:19)
>       at Array.map ()
>       at resolveDependencies (/Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:374:16)
>       at /Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:212:33
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (/Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:313)
>       at /Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:297:473
>       at

However I have checked in the directory and in fact */Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/xdate/src/xdate.js* does exist. However I do not see any of this part: (.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`

As to how */Users/Alex/Documents/workspace/mobile/node_modules/xdate/src/xdate.js/index* can exist, that doesn't make sense because *xdate.js* is not a directory.

Any help?

Comment: stop the packager and run it again with **react-native start**

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It Usually happens if you try to install a module while your packager is open.

Try to delete `node_modules` folder and close the `packager`.
Then reinstall everything by `npm install` in your project directory.

Comment: I've solved `bundling failed referenceerror module not registered in graph` just by closing the packager. Thanks

Comment: how to close packager?

Comment: press Ctrl+C inside CLI to turn off Packager or NPM. You can also use "taskkill /f /im node.exe" for Windows and "killall -9 node" for Linux

Comment: having similar issue with fs, not resolved by this.

Comment: I have many libraries installed in my project. And every time I do `npm install`, I have to do again manual linking to some of the libraries to fix some issues. Maybe there is a way to save previous linking setup for the libraries, but if there is not this option, the `npm install` to me is a nightmare.

Comment: Provided reason is right but you don't need to reinstall everything. Only restarting the packager should work. But you never know how react-native works.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal same here, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 43):

First close your JavaScript bundler (Metro bundler in my case) and restart the application. This will create fresh dependency graph. This should solve the issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer as the issue is with the dependency graph created by the bundler and has nothing to do with the node_modules folder.

Comment: This was the perfect Answer for me.
I used GIT and switched between the branch. So make sure, after you've switched the branch (and if install of new Components via yarn/npn or pod was necessary)... close the Terminal-Window (with Headline "Metro-Bundler") which was open in the Background. Then hit the "build" Button in Xcode again. After that it works again for me without any error.

Comment: RN 0.63.3 confirmed to work.
Curious that this is the only place where a sensible answer can be found. Thanks!
PS. in this version you'll get the message that FS.common.js from "main" field could not be resolved.

Comment: If you are using mac, Logout from mac and then run ```npm install``` and then ```npm run start --reset-cache```.
Do give it a shot, i tried everything, nothing except this. Might be some caching issue in packager itself. No need to delete ```node_modules```.

Answer (score 9):

**Just restart the bundler - no need to delete the Node Modules folder**

I came across this issue when adding and using react-native-elements when using VS Code and Android Studio emulator on Linux Mint

In VS Code I had a terminal running Expo with Metro Bundler via 'npm start' command. After installing the react-native-elements in the folder (using 'npm install --save react-native-elements') and adding the import into the .js file I got the "*However, this package itself specifies a main module field that could not be resolved" error*.

In my case, this just involved a ^C in the terminal session to stop the Metro bundler and then running 'npm start' again. There was no need to delete the node modules folder at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still getting the error even after deleting the `./node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again, try doing the install with the `--update-binary` flag, i.e `npm install --update-binary`. This should clear out and rebuild any previously built packages on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't delete the node modules folder.
The bundler has least to deal with node modules folder.

Instead close all the terminals. If using VS-code close that also.

Close all the local host server ports and if possible restart the system.
This might solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone have same issue, and remove node_module not working. Then you can try remove all node_module, package lock and using yarn to install node_module instead npm. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above helped me except for restarting my MacBook. Wasted 30 minutes trying to fix this issue as I couldn't believe restarting my computer could be a solution.